# DropBox File Encryption Upload in Android

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload a file to DropBox which works fine. However, I want to be able to encrypt this file before it is uploaded. I have tried doing a google search and can't find anything.

Thanks for any help you can provide.